# Request timed out error in ASIHTTPRequest - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest`, even though i am using `[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:30];` i end up with a `Request timed out error (status 408 error)` before 30 seconds.

Why is this, and how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using the below function?

```
[requestObj setTimeOutSeconds:300.0];
```

Comment: Yes i did use `setTimeOutSeconds`, but didn't set it to `300.0`, i set it to `30.0` instead.